# How to base an element's CSS of of it's previous adjacent sibling's CSS?

Tags: css, angularjs, margin

I'm trying to make a set of buttons that stick to the bottom of the page and are separated by a constant amount of space.  I'm using angularJS's ng-repeat directive to grab data via an ajax request which I then use to display the buttons.

My problem lies in making the buttons be separated by a constant amount.

http://jsfiddle.net/8obgugd7/

As you can see, three of the buttons are in the exact same space, because the margins are not cumulative.  Is there any way that I could use CSS to determine an element's margin based on the previous adjacent sibling?

Something like:

```
.sticky-footer{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   margin-left: 20px;
}

.sticky-footer + .sticky-footer{
   margin-left = (previous sibling's margin) + 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. Make a container, place it, and then just push buttons inside

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8obgugd7/2/)

```
.sticky-footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sticky-footer button {
    margin-left:20px;
}

<div class="sticky-footer">
    <button>click me</button>
    <button>click me</button>
    <button>click me</button>
    <button>click me</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm relatively new to CSS.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JulianSniffen you don't have to apologize me, sure thing, everyone starts somewhere :)